# error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to C++ , I created a Single Document Interface application with MS Visual C++.
when I compile it,some errors have occurred in header file called Day10 SDIDOC.h as follows

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
error C2501: 'CLine' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
error C2501: 'GetLine' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
error C2501: 'CLine' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
error C2501: 'AddLine' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
```

my files are

**Day10 SDIDOC.h**

```
public:
CLine * GetLine(int nIndex);
int GetLineCount();
CLine * AddLine(CPoint ptFrom,CPoint ptTo);
CObArray m_oaLines;
virtual ~CDay10SDIDoc();
#ifdef _DEBUG
virtual void AssertValid() const;
virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
#endif
```

these GetLine() and AddLine() methods implement  like this in Day10 SDIDOC.cpp

**Day10 SDIDOC.cpp**

```
CLine * CDay10SDIDoc::AddLine(CPoint ptFrom, CPoint ptTo)
{
//create a new CLine Object
CLine *pLine = new CLine(ptFrom,ptTo);

try
{
   //Add the new line to the object array
m_oaLines.Add(pLine);

   //Mark the document as dirty(unsaved)
   SetModifiedFlag();
 }
//Did we run into a memory exception ?
 catch(CMemoryException* perr)
{
   //Display a message for the user,giving the bad new
   AfxMessageBox("Out of Memory",MB_ICONSTOP|MB_OK);

   //Did we create a line object?
   if(pLine)
   {
   //Delete it
   delete pLine;
    pLine = NULL;
   }
   //delete the exception object
 perr->Delete();
}
  return pLine;
  }
```

And GetLine Method

```
CLine * CDay10SDIDoc::GetLine(int nIndex)
{
return (CLine*) m_oaLines[nIndex];

}
```

I can't understand what wrong with.
Please Give me a solution for that.
Thank you...

Comment: Did you include whatever header contains `CLine`?

Comment: Use [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and get better error messages!

Answer (score 2):

It appears your compiler **cannot see the declaration** for `CLine` at the point when it parses the 2 functions. Because of this it has no idea what that name is, and thus errors out.

You can solve this by **including the header** to the definition of `CLine` or adding just a **forward declaration** at the top of `Day10 SDIDOC.h` and including the header in the cpp file. A forward declaration would suffice since you use only a pointer to `CLine` and do not define a `CLine` object or use its definition in anyway in the header.

Comment: Just forward declaring `Cline` in header will resolve the compilation errors for the header file, Since it does not need to see the details of `CLine`, it can accept and work with `CLine` as an *Incomplete type*, but the cpp needs to see the definition of `CLine`, it cannot work with the Incomplete type.

Comment: @AlokSave, Good point, though you could argue against the pointer usage in the first place.

Comment: @AlokSave isnt that my second suggestion exactly? I have added more explanation to make it clearer

Comment: Thanks Karthik,But i include heder file to Day10 SDIDOC.CPP file as follows,#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Day 10 SDI.h"
#include "Line.h"

#include "Day 10 SDIDoc.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

Comment: @user1685914 you might still want to add a forward declaration just to be safe. Add `class CLine;` near the top of the header.

Comment: done but it is not working. still occurs errors